# How can I find the maximum value of this function?

Tags: linear-programming, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

For given values of $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, b \in \mathbb{R}^m$, how can I find the value of:

$$
\max_{x \in [0,1]^n} \|Ax+b \|_1
$$

Or is this problem NP-hard?

Comment: Would anyone care to explain the close votes?  This doesn't look immediately obvious to me.

Comment: Is $B=(b_{i,j})_{i,j}$ quadratic? If I understand u correctly u want to minimize $\|Ax-b\|_{1}$ where $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $b\in \mathbb{R}^m$ subject to the constraint $x \in [0,1]^n$.

Comment: @user35593 : maximize, not minimize.

Comment: @user35593: Yes you are correct, I can reformulate the problem to matrix form. However, as Robert Israel mentions it is a maximization problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that since the objective is convex, 
there are optimal solutions that are extreme points of the feasible region, i.e. we can assume all $x_i \in \{0,1\}$.

We can encode an Ising hamiltonian in this problem, with spins $\sigma_i = (-1, 1)$ corresponding to $x_i = (0, 1)$.

Thus a term 
$$J \sigma_1 \sigma_2 = \cases{  | J x_1 + J x_2 - 2 J| - J & if $J > 0$\cr
     |J x_1- J x_2| + J & if $J < 0$  }$$
while for single spins
$$ h \sigma = \cases{|2h x | - h & if $h > 0$\cr |2hx - 2h| + h & if $h < 0$\cr}$$

Maximizing (or minimizing) such a Hamiltonian is well-known to be NP-hard.

Comment: Too bad it is NP-hard since I need to solve it for a real world application. I guess I need keep $n$ small in order to test all combinations. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: You can probably do a lot better than "test all combinations".